# ¿Es posible que una página web solamente funcione si está incrustada en un iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Quiero saber si es posible que una página funcione solamente si está llamada en un iframe

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Si se puede pero hay ciertas condiciones a verificar, checa este [enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***¿Es posible que una página web solamente funcione si está incrustada en un iframe?***

Saludos,

Claro que sí es posible, en informática prácticamente todo es posible, ahora analicemos si realmente es conveniente y si debes o no hacerlo.

En resumidas cuentas un `iframe` es toda una estructura `HTML` que está incrustado dentro de otra página Web, podemos insertar uno o más en nuestra página Web.

En ocasiones está bien usar `iframe` para poner contenido como imagenes, videos, juegos siempre y cuando sean de fácil acceso y tengamos permisos para hacerlo.
Si usas muchos `iframe` afectará la velocidad de tu página Web, no deber usarlo como parte esencial de tu sitio, sino más bien como una parte de contenido dentro del mismo.

Además, cada vez que subes un `iframe`, también se cargan los comandos de esa página. Esto puede inflar Google Analytics o Visitas a la página HubSpot de la página en que pusiste el iframe.

Comment: Ok, es posible hacerlo, la pregunta (que no tiene solución en esta respuesta) es: ¿Cómo?