# Mostrar pagina unicamente si se abre en iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Tengo una pagina cuya URL es algo así: `https://example.com/home/inicio.php`

Dentro tengo un enlace, cuando le doy clic, me carga en un iframe otra pagina que está en mi mismo sitio, por ejemplo: `https://example.com/home/contacto.php`

Para la demostración, el enlace apunta a Wikipedia.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <!-- 
    <a href="contacto.php" target="iframe_a">CLIC</a> 
  -->
    <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org" target="iframe_a">CLIC</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<iframe src="example.com" name="iframe_a" height="200px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

Ahora, **sé que cualquier persona podría simplemente hacer clic derecho sobre el enlace y abrirlo en otra pestaña**. Necesito que cuando esto suceda, la página `home/contacto.php` me detecte que no está dentro del iframe en la página `home/inicio.php` y me deniegue el acceso, se oculte o no me permita interacción, o me muestra una alerta mínimo.

Buscando en el sitio, [encontré esta misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255491/), pero la supuesta respuesta no aclara cómo hacerlo.

Se me ocurre que la estrucuta `<ul><li><a>...` de la pagina `home/inicio.php`, sea un form que me pase por método POST un identificador a la pagina del iframe, y sino lo encuentra (al acceder directamente), bloquee el acceso.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Ya probaste con `if (window.parent === window) {
    location = "https://fuera-de-aqui.com/";
}` ? Igual considera que yo podría, o apagar JS, o crear un iframe que me lleve a tu URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el iframe contiene un PHP puedes hacerlo poniendo esto al principio de **contacto.php** de este modo:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'http://localhost/home/inicio.php' 
   OR $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST'] !== 'iframe')  {
    die("Esto no está permitido!!");
}
?>
<h1>Hola mundo</h1>
```

donde:

- **http://localhost/home/inicio.php** es la url completa desde donde quieres servir el iframe

aunque eso no te asegura otros intentos de acceso mediante cURL o similares que puedan trucar headers, pero al menos te libras de los del botón derecho.

Más info sobre [HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Dest)